# Angular - How to resolve Type 'Observable<ILoginResponse | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<ILoginResponse>'

Tags: angular

In Angular-13, I have this JSON response from Web API:

```
{
"data": {
    "id": "3333-3841-43d1-9bae-dddd",
    "token": "anythingsdsdsdsds",
    "user": {
        "id": 33333-3841-43d1-9bae-ea32e1165021",
        "firstName": "Janet",
        "lastName": "Wilow",
        "email": "janet@email.com",
        "userName": "JWilow"
      },
    "roles": [
        "Teacher"
     ],
    "expires": "2022-06-23T15:01:21.4727432+01:00",
    "refreshToken": "9333333-e67e-4deb-84a6-6efdraw"
},
"successful": true,
"message": "Login Successfully",
"statusCode": 200
}
```

I want to implement it in my Angular auth.service for the login. I have done this in Angular:

ILoginRequest:

```
export interface ILoginRequest {
  userName: string;
  password: string;
}
```

ILoginResponse:

```
export interface IUser {
  id: string;
  firstName?: string;
  lastName?: string;
  email: string;
  userName: string;
  isAdmin: boolean;
  isPasswordChanged: boolean;
  mobileNumber: string;
  lastLogin: Date;
  fullname: string;
}

export interface IData {
  id: string;
  token: string;
  user: IUser;
  roles: string[];
  expires: Date;
  refreshToken: string;
}

export interface ILoginResponse {
  data: IData;
  successful: boolean;
  message: string;
  statusCode: number;
}
```

Then at last I have this:

auth.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BehaviorSubject, ReplaySubject, of } from 'rxjs';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { ILoginRequest } from 'src/app/features/auth/models/login-request';
import { ILoginResponse } from 'src/app/features/auth/models/login-response';
import { map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  baseUrl = environment.baseHost;
  private currentUserSource = new ReplaySubject<ILoginResponse | null>(1);
  currentUser$ = this.currentUserSource.asObservable();
  token = localStorage.getItem('token');

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private router: Router,
    private toastr: ToastrService
    ) { }

  login(model: ILoginRequest): Observable<ILoginResponse> {
    return this.http.post<ILoginResponse>(`${this.baseUrl} +'login`, model).pipe(
      map((data:ILoginResponse)=>{
        if(data.successful == true){
          return data;
        }
        else{
          console.log(data.successful);
        }
      })
    );
  }
}
```

But I got this error in the auth.service:

```
Type 'Observable<ILoginResponse | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<ILoginResponse>'.
  Type 'ILoginResponse | undefined' is not assignable to type 'ILoginResponse'.
    Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'ILoginResponse'.ts(2322)
```

and the of:

> ```
> return this.http.post<ILoginResponse>(`${this.baseUrl} +'login`, model).pipe(
>   map((data:ILoginResponse)=>{
>     if(data.successful == true){
>       return data;
>     }
>     else{
>       console.log(data.successful);
>     }
>   })
> );
> ```

is highlighted.

I want to return everything in ILoginResponse.

How do I get it sorted out?

Thank you

Comment: What have I done wrong please?

Comment: But I need an explanation. This is too strict. I don't just understand. I can't even use the forum again

Comment: Share Component code as well where you are calling this service

Answer (score 0):

The error message is quite clear. `.map()` require to return value. The problem is you only return value when `data.successful` is `true`.

```js
return this.http.post<ILoginResponse>(`${this.baseUrl} +'login`, model).pipe(
  map((data:ILoginResponse) => {
    
    if (!data.successful)
      console.log(data.successful);

    return data;
  })
);
```

Or I would suggest using [`.tap()`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/tap) as `.map()` aimed at transforming and returning a new set of data. While `.tap()` is used for doing the tasks while keeping the data unchanged and returned.

```js
return this.http.post<ILoginResponse>(`${this.baseUrl} +'login`, model).pipe(
  tap((data:ILoginResponse) => {
    
    if (!data.successful)
      console.log(data.successful);
  })
);
```